# Populating Listview making my other parameter empty

Tags: android, listview, buttonclick

I am populating an array with upload button click and viewing them in listview but probelem is that after clicking on upload button it making my other values in same activity empty even the spinner value also gets empty

Here is my upload button click code

```
        public void uploadfile(View view){
        edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFile);
        List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> number = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> status = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(FullPath != null)
        {
                    // CSV UPLOADER
            try{
                File csvfile = new File(FullPath);
                FileInputStream csvStream = new FileInputStream(csvfile);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csvStream));
                String[] rowData = null;
                String dataRow = in.readLine();
                        while (dataRow != null){
                            String[] RowData = dataRow.split(",");
                            name.add(new String(RowData[0]));
                            number.add(new String(RowData[1]));
                            status.add("unsent");
                            dataRow = in.readLine();
            }
                       in.close();
                       Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, "CSV Has uploaded", 2000).show();
                       setContentView(R.layout.new_message);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, e.toString(), 2000).show();
            }
            //CSV Uploaded
            //View CSV into an array
            try{
            setContentView(R.layout.new_message);   
            ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            for(int i=0;i<name.size();i++)
            {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("name",name.get(i));
                map.put("number",number.get(i));
                map.put("status",status.get(i));
                mylist.add(map);
            }
            SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(NewMessage.this, mylist, R.layout.view_csv, new String[] {"name","number","status"}, new int[] {R.id.t1,R.id.t2,R.id.t3});
            lv.setAdapter(mSchedule);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, e.toString(), 2000).show();
            }
//Viewing Finish Here

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, "No File Selected", 2000).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The calls to `setContentView(R.layout.new_message);` replace the Activity's entire layout. Is that what you mean to do?

Comment: Ok let me check for it

Comment: Thats it what i want thank you so much :). Frustation lead to this :P